# Golang grpc go.mod issue

Tags: go

Hi guys does anyone would know what is the issue with this package:

```
go: loading module retractions for github.com/googleapis/gax-go/v2@v2.0.1: parsing go.mod: go.mod:8:2: require google.golang.org/genproto: version "b98a9ff5e252" invalid: must be of the form v1.2.3
```

after doing `go get -u ./...` or how to work around to fix this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The go.mod file of the module you are trying to import is broken. As the message you posted says, the version number should start with "v" (see [here](https://go.dev/doc/modules/gomod-ref#require-syntax))

It seems that the module was broken by a bot https://github.com/googleapis/gax-go/commit/735836c34b8124d657958d469998865569e14742

The solution would be to revert the commit on the googleapis/gax-go repository.

Comment: [v2.51](https://github.com/googleapis/gax-go/releases/tag/v2.5.1) has now been released and should resolve this (likely that no changes will be required in the OP's code as they are using `2.0.1` so it looks like the failure was just in loading [retractions](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-retract)).

Comment: yes that worked, however it seems that today the problem resolved itself and did upgraded to `go: upgraded github.com/googleapis/gax-go/v2 v2.4.0 => v2.5.1`